# Notation for the edge set incident on a vertex $v$

Tags: graph-theory, notation

How I can denote the set of edges incident on a vertex $v$ in a graph? Any suggestion/reference that has this?

I know that the set of **vertices** incident on $v$ is $N(v)$ (set of neighbors of a vertex), but the edges set, I do not know!

Comment: Why do you think you need notation for this set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the undirected graphs: Assume $u$ is your given vertex, then what I would  recommend is $\forall v \in V s.t. (u, v) \in E.
$

For the directed case:
If v is your starting point in the edge/arc, then $\forall u \in V, s.t. (v, u) \in E.$

If v is your endpoint, then $\forall u \in V, s.t. (u, v) \in E.$

And then you could basically redefine a set, like.
Given a vertex $v$, let $S(v) = \{ e \in E: \forall u \in V, e=(v, u) \in E\}$.

Comment: Sorry, but I thought it would Tex this by default, I hope this is still readable though...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).